# How to make sorting through gridView method POST?

Tags: php, gridview, yii, yii-extensions

How to make sorting through gridView method POST?

```
return new CustomActiveDataProvider($this, [
            'criteria' => $criteria,
            'sort' => [
                'defaultOrder' => 'cdate DESC'
            ],
            'pagination' => $this->searchFrom || $this->searchTo || $this->district_key || $this->city_key ? false : ['pageSize' => 100]
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that **It's not Possible!**

I've just gone through the [Official Yii API Documentation for the CSort class](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSort) and all parameter references are through `$_GET`

Comment: Not prompt then, I have a filter to search for them through the $ _POST, $ _GET as a string with each request all complemented